# ActionView attribute of Android menu item is always null

Tags: xamarin, menu, actionview

I want to Animate Menu item by some logic but menu item with the id of refresh has null in property of ActionView . What am i wrong ?

Menu Item Xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
      <item
           android:id="@+id/refresh"
           android:icon="@drawable/plus_white"
           local:showAsAction="ifRoom"
           local:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.ImageView"
           android:title="Refresh" />
      <item
           android:id="@+id/favoritePodcast"
           android:icon="@drawable/favorite_star"
           local:showAsAction="ifRoom"
           android:title="Favorite" />

    </menu>
```

OnCreateOption::

```
     public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
            {
                MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.MainMenu, menu);

                if (_notified)
                {
                    IMenuItem item = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.refresh);
                    var itemView= item.ActionView.JavaCast<Android.Widget.ImageView>();

                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(ApplicationContext,
                                                       Resource.Animation.fade_in);

                    itemView.StartAnimation(anim);
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Notified", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }

                return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            }
```

The BreakPoint View:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found answer.
Thanks to robbit for help: https://forums.xamarin.com/profile/355640/robbit
I define a new layout for menu item like this :

NewItemRefresh.axml:>>>>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right" >

  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:src="@drawable/plus_white"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

and add android:actionLayout="@layout/NewItemRefresh" to menu item

Now the menu item changed :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
      <item
           android:id="@+id/refresh"
           android:icon="@drawable/plus_white"
           local:showAsAction="ifRoom"
           local:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.ImageView" 
           android:actionLayout="@layout/NewItemRefresh"
           android:title="Refresh" />
      <item
           android:id="@+id/favoritePodcast"
           android:icon="@drawable/favorite_star"
           local:showAsAction="ifRoom"
           android:title="Favorite" />

    </menu>
```

And OnCreateOptionsMenu:

```
     public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
            {
                MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.MainMenu, menu);

                if (_notified)
                {
                    IMenuItem item = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.refresh);
                    View view = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.NewItemRefresh, null);
                    item.SetActionView(view);
                    var itemView= item.ActionView.JavaCast<Android.Widget.RelativeLayout>();

                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(ApplicationContext,
                                                       Resource.Animation.fade_in);

                    itemView.StartAnimation(anim);
                    Toast.MakeText(this, "Notified", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }

                return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            }
```

So I can animate menu item by some logic .